# Angular - Pros and Cons of using the hashtag in the URL

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app I know I can remove the hashtag in the URL by using the code:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and setting the base href in my index file `<base href="/">`

However - what are the pros and cons of not using the hashtag.

Surely the Angular team placed it there for some reason and the only advantage I can see of not having it is 'it looks nicer'.

Interested to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Using the hashtag allows this to work with older browsers. Without makes use of the HTML5 push state. If you need to support old browsers, use the hashtag.see here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Comment: But according the the docs it states: "If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser, the $location service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs automatically."

Comment: So then it's a matter of consistency. If someone shares a link to your page with the hashtag, it would look different from a link shared from an HTML5 app.

Comment: Ah - thats a valid point